# How to add validation to my form?

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have a php form that is adding information to my sql database, i need it to only accept numbers in the text box.

This is my php form

```
<form id="MakeBid" action="MakeBid.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="propertyID" value="1" />
    <div>Bid Now
        <input type="text" name="pricesoldfor" />
    </div>
    <input id="submit" input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Server-side or client-side validation? What have you tried? Where exactly are you having problems?

Comment: this would be the client side of things, I have validation on the server side, just need an error message to appear if the customer has inserted letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client-side for feedback without loading, you can do something like

```
<form [...] onsubmit="if( !this.pricesoldfor.match(/\d+/) ) { 
     alert('Please enter only numbers for the price!'); return false; 
}">
```

(I've written this example inline - as your form will probably be larger, I would advise you not to use the attribute onsubmit and instead attach a proper event handler. Have a look at [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault) as well as this is usually a better alternative to `return false`.)

What you will really need to do is validate in your *PHP* (server-side) that it is only numbers before you save it to the database. For example like this:

```
if((string)(int)$input === $input) { /*was a number*/ } else { /*was not a number*/ }
```

Bear in mind both of these will only allow full numbers (integers), so no "35.43" or similar. Have a look at [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript for client-side validation. This isnt very secure, but its fast and can be used to provide a responsive user experience, but should always be backed up with server-side validation.

You can use a mix of regular expressions and if/else or case/switch to see what characters have been typed in.

```
if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]", $textfield)) 
// display error message
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$num = 123456;
if(!filter_var($num, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))
 {
 echo("Not number");
 }
else
 {
 echo("Number");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

visit for all type of validation

http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/

and demo is below

http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html